# Bukkit passing a player of event to another class

Tags: java, bukkit

So I am struggling with something. I have 2 seperate classes. 1 class for runnable and 1 class for event handling. Is there any way I can pass the player of event(e.getPlayer) to another class? I am trying to update the name of the item for cooldown purposes. Here is my codes

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@EventHandler
public void ItemRightClick(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    Action a = e.getAction();
    ItemStack item = p.getItemInHand();
    ItemMeta itemmeta = item.getItemMeta();



    if(a == Action.PHYSICAL) return;
    if(!p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.DIAMOND_HOE)) return;
    if(!itemmeta.getDisplayName().contains("Wand of Regen")) return;
    if(cooldown.containsKey(p)) {
        if(cooldown.get(p) + cooldownTime <= System.currentTimeMillis()) { 
            cooldown.remove(p);
            } else {
                if((int) (cooldown.get(p) + cooldownTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000 != 0) {
                itemmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Wand of Regen" + ChatColor.GRAY + " - " + ChatColor.AQUA + "Remaining " + ChatColor.GREEN + (int) (cooldown.get(p) + cooldownTime - System.currentTimeMillis()) / 1000 + ChatColor.AQUA + " seconds");
                item.setItemMeta(itemmeta);
                return;
                }
                itemmeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.RED + "Wand of Regen" + ChatColor.GRAY + " - " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Ready");
                item.setItemMeta(itemmeta);
            }
        }

        p.addPotionEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 5 * 100, 3));
        p.sendMessage("Regen activated");
        cooldown.put(p, System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
}
```

This is the runnable class

```
    public class StepEvent extends BukkitRunnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `StepEvent` class with a Player in it's constructor, like this:

```
public class StepEvent extends BukkitRunnable {
    private Player passedPlayer;

    public StepEvent(Player passedPlayer) {
        this.passedPlayer = passedPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        passedPlayer.doStuff();
    }


}
```

And whenever you need to use this Runnable with the player, create an instance of it, as you would do normally:

```
StepEvent stepEventWithPlayer = new StepEvent(playerToBePassed);
```

Comment: where do I get the player from other class?

Comment: When you construct your Runnable. When you use "new StepEvent(xxx)", xxx is the player that you pass from the other class

Comment: I create the runnable on my main class but the player I want to pass is on event handler so?